# Convert String of this "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" format to LocalDate

Tags: java, java-8, simpledateformat, localdate

I want to convert the string date (with timezone specified) to LocalDate.

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";
String date = "2019-08-31T17:00:00.000-07:00";

System.out.println("LocalDate: " + LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)));
System.out.println("Date: " + new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(date));
```

and output of the above code is

```
LocalDate: 2019-08-31
Date: Sun Sep 01 05:30:00 IST 2019
```

I am not able to get the same result that got from SimpleDateFormat. I want 2019-09-01 in LocalDate.

Comment: Sounds stupid, since the date is on 08-31. Care to clarify by what logic do you want 09-01 instead?

Comment: I am able to get 2019-09-01 in SimpleDateFormat and now I am using LocalDate and want the same answer. I have also tried OffsetDateTime and ZonedDateTime but not able to get 2019-09-01.

Comment: My question is how do you know that the SimpleDateFormat was not completely buggy and irremediably wrong

Comment: @deHaar I am able to get 2019-09-01 in SimpleDateFormat. I want LocalDate with +5.30 (IST)

Comment: Then do parse the date as OffsetDateTime, then convert it, withOffsetSameInstant(), to an offset of +5:30. use toLocalDate() on the result if your end goal is a LocalDate

Comment: @kumesana SimpleDateFormat converts that string to Date with IST and wants that result in java.time API.

Comment: okay, good. I think Sweeper's answer addresses that perfectly

Comment: This question has minimal, reproducible example, expected output (2019-09-01) and observed output (2019-08-31). Are the downvotes because of lack of clarity, or what? (I upvoted.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the old `Date` class represents a *point in time*, not a local date. It just so happens that `Date.toString` outputs the string as if it is in the system time zone.

The java.time API forces you to think more deeply about what you want. It provides you different types to represent different temporal concepts. `LocalDate.parse` will only interpret the "local date" part of the string.

Your date string represents an `OffsetDateTime`, so you should use `OffsetDateTime.parse`. Now you have a `LocalDateTime` plus a `ZoneOffset`. To make it 09-01, you have to change its zone, while keeping it the same instant, which can be done with `atZoneSameInstant`, and then get the local date part of it:

```
System.out.println("LocalDate: " +
        OffsetDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format))
                .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDate());
```

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, you got my question and gave a perfect answer.